# ID fica a null, quando entro dos detalhes pelo index

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Quando entro nos detalhes do registo pelo index do ID fica sempre a null.

> http://localhost:17542/Disponibilidade/Detalhes/0

Controlador Detalhes:

```
public ActionResult Detalhes(int? id)
        {
            var disponibilidade = db.Disponibilidade.Where(d => d.DisponibilidadeID == id).FirstOrDefault();

            if (disponibilidade == null)
            {
                return new HttpNotFoundResult();
            }
            DisponibilidadeViewModel model = new DisponibilidadeViewModel()
            {     
                AnoPastoral = disponibilidade.AnoPastoral,
                DiaDisponivel = disponibilidade.DiaDisponivel,
                HoraDisponivel = disponibilidade.HoraDisponivel,
                Observacoes = disponibilidade.Observacoes
            }; 
            return View(model);
        }
```

Controlador Create:

```
public ActionResult CriarDisponibilidade([Bind(Include = "DisponibilidadeID,AnoPastoral,DiaDisponivel,HoraDisponivel,Observacoes,CatequistaID")] Disponibilidade disponibilidade)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Disponibilidade.Add(disponibilidade);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(disponibilidade);
        }
```

Action Index:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebAppCatechesis2.ViewModels.DisponibilidadeViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_mytemplate.cshtml";
}

<div id="page-wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h1 class="page-header">Lista Disponibilidades de cada catequista</h1>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    Futuramente vai ter aqui opções
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th class="info">
                                        Nome do Catequista
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="info">
                                        AnoPastoral
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="info">
                                        DiaDisponivel
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="info">
                                        HoraDisponivel
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="info">
                                        Observacoes
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="info">
                                        Opções
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @foreach (var item in Model)
                                {
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Nome)
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.AnoPastoral)
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.DiaDisponivel)
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.HoraDisponivel)
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Observacoes)
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @Html.ActionLink("Editar", "Editar", new { id = item.DisponibilidadeID }) |
                                            @Html.ActionLink("Detalhes", "Detalhes", new { id = item.DisponibilidadeID }) |
                                            @Html.ActionLink("Apagar", "Apagar", new { id = item.DisponibilidadeID })
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                }
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.table-responsive -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.panel-body -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.panel -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
    </div>
</div>
```

ViewModel:

```
 public class DisponibilidadeViewModel
    {
        public int DisponibilidadeID { get; set; }
        public String Nome { get; set; }
        public String AnoPastoral { get; set; }
        public String DiaDisponivel { get; set; }
        public String HoraDisponivel { get; set; }
        public String Observacoes { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Pode colocar na sua pergunta como você está fazendo para chamar essa URL?

Comment: Já adicionei a alteração

Comment: O link é chamado de uma *View* associada a `DisponibilidadeController`? Não devia ir ID 0. Sabe me dizer por que o link está sendo gerado com essa ID 0?

Comment: Se o id for posto manualmente no url funciona perfeitamente. Mas não percebo o porquê de ser 0.

Comment: Sim, o problema é obviamente o link. Pode colocar na sua pergunta a *Action* que salva uma disponibilidade?

Comment: As minhas disponibilidades estão a ser guardadas correctamente.Com os ID correctos.Vou por a View completa

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33015/discussion-between-user10271-and-cigano-morrison-mendez).

Comment: Em cima está a action de salta uma disponibilidade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você está usando um *ViewModel* para suas *Views*, precisa preencher `DisponibilidadeID`, senão obviamente não vai funcionar:

```
        DisponibilidadeViewModel model = new DisponibilidadeViewModel()
        {   
            DisponibilidadeID = disponibilidade.DisponibilidadeID,
            AnoPastoral = disponibilidade.AnoPastoral,
            DiaDisponivel = disponibilidade.DiaDisponivel,
            HoraDisponivel = disponibilidade.HoraDisponivel,
            Observacoes = disponibilidade.Observacoes
        };
```

Problema controlador Index:

```
Select new DisponibilidadeViewModel { Nome = p.Nome, DisponibilidadeID = d.DisponibilidadeID, AnoPastoral = d.AnoPastoral, DiaDisponivel = d.DiaDisponivel, HoraDisponivel = d.HoraDisponivel, Observacoes = d.Observacoes });
```

Faltava: `DisponibilidadeID = d.DisponibilidadeID`

Comment: Já tinha feito isso, o problema é que quando faço click nos Detalhes do Index ele nem entra no metodo "ActionResult Detalhes".

Comment: Vou precisar da *Action* Index na sua pergunta também.

Comment: Foi alterado com  o _Action_ Index, e _Model View_

Comment: Então, é isso mesmo. Você não está preenchendo `DisponibilidadeID`, por isso o erro.

Comment: Como posso preencher isso na _ViewModel_?

Comment: Eu já coloquei isso na minha resposta. Ainda não está claro?

Comment: `DisponibilidadeID = disponibilidade.DisponibilidadeID,`, este campo só é preenchido se colocar o ID no URL.

Comment: `var disponibilidade = db.Disponibilidade.Where(d => d.DisponibilidadeID == id).FirstOrDefault();`,está a _NULL_ e não consigo contornar isto.

Comment: Acho que você não entendeu. O preenchimento errado está na Index. Não em Detalhes. Em Detalhes está tudo certo.

Comment: Sorry. Ok já percebi o meu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Pela minha experiencia eu posso te dizer o seguinte.

Se você mudar a URL para :

> http://localhost:17542/Disponibilidade/Detalhes?id=0

Vai funcionar do jeito que está...

Agora, para fazer essa URL da pergunta funcionar basta você colocar a seguinte linha no arquivo `Route.Config.cs`

```
        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

Ficaria assim:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();


            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

E colocar a seguinte anotação no seu método:

```
    [Route("seucontrole/detalhes/{id}")]
```

Com isso a rota com `/0` funciona.

Comment: Penso que o meu problema não seja de Rotas, mas do ID, que nao é injectado no método.

Comment: Roda o seu projeto e executa a URL como eu coloquei na resposta, o valor vai certinho. Faz o teste pra você ver. Sem mudar nada, só chama a URL dessa forma

Comment: Já testei e não funcionou, mas se por o ID manualmente no URL funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: O que é por manualmente, o que mudaria nessa url manualmente para funcionar? http://localhost:17542/Disponibilidade/Detalhes?id=0

Comment: Se colocar o ID no URL funciona perfeitamente

Comment: Então, é isso que eu falei... Se fizer o que eu disse na resposta a sua rota (Original da pergunta) vai funcionar...

Comment: Não funciona. Penso que fiz tudo certo